# MYSQL LEFT JOIN Return value from empty table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm querying 3 tables with 1 query with MySQL.
I'm using the `JOIN` method as follows:

1. table have column "test_column" value="test_value"
2. table have column "test_column" value="test_value"
3. table have column "test_column" value=NULL

I'getting always `test_column` value is NULL, but I would like to have the value "test_value"

```
    $sql  = "SELECT _t.*, _t1.*, _t2.*";
    $sql .= "FROM _test as _t ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN _test1 as _t1 ";
    $sql .= "ON _t.test_column=_t1.test_column ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN _test2 as _t2 ";
    $sql .= "ON _t.test_column = _t2.test_column ";
    $sql .= "WHERE _t.test_column ='test_value'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is selecting multiple columns named `test_column`. When you get the results in PHP, `$_row['test_column']` will contain the value from the last one, which is `_test2.test_column`, which is `NULL`.

You should use a column alias so you can get the column from a specific table.

```
$sql = "SELECT _t.test_column AS t_test_column, _t.*, _t1.*, _t2.*";
```

Then use `$row['t_test_column']` to get the value.

Comment: I'm sorry 3. table is empty not any record!

Comment: When you do a LEFT JOIN, you get null values for all the columns from the table if there's no match.